# VueJS, style tag not working or displaying the stlye

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a Vuejs component but the style tag is not working. example for the cancel button I have a class cancel, and I want to color it red using the style tag but for some reason it doesn't work. it won't change the color to red.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        ADD HERE

        <button class="cancel" @click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    .cancel{
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        cancel(){
            this.$emit('show','view');
        }, 
    }
}
</script>
```

but if I do like

```
<button class="cancel" @click="cancel()" style="color:red">Cancel</button>
```

doing it inline works.

Comment: The color might be getting applied and cascaded by some other css file. Your inline code works because inline has the highest priority.

Comment: I don't think this is the case cuz doing random class name still doesn't apply the style.

Comment: can you try giving '!important' to the css?

Comment: i tried color: red !important; but still not displaying